# Ruby: I have a hash with keys = str.split(//) and values = indices of those chars. How do i add multiple indices to value if more than 1 chars exists

Tags: ruby

I currently have this written up for turning my string elements into a hash[key] with its indices as values

```
def char_indices(str)
  array = str.split(//)
  hash = array.each_with_object({}).with_index {|(el, h), i| h[el] = []<<i}
  p hash
end
```

which returns

```
{"m"=>[0], "i"=>[10], "s"=>[6], "p"=>[9]}

{"c"=>[0], "l"=>[1], "a"=>[2], "s"=>[4], "r"=>[5], "o"=>[7], "m"=>[8]}
```

but I need

```
char_indices('mississippi')   # => {"m"=>[0], "i"=>[1, 4, 7, 10], "s"=>[2, 3, 5, 6], "p"=>[8, 9]}
char_indices('classroom')     # => {"c"=>[0], "l"=>[1], "a"=>[2], "s"=>[3, 4], "r"=>[5], "o"=>[6, 7], "m"=>[8]}
```

problem is my value is getting replaced each time and i only end up with the last value.

how can i add each recurring location to value in a ruby like fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def char_indices(str)
  str.each_char.
      with_index.
      with_object({}) do |(c,i),h|
        (h[c] ||= []) << i
      end
end
```

```
char_indices('mississippi')
  #=> {"m"=>[0], "i"=>[1, 4, 7, 10], "s"=>[2, 3, 5, 6], "p"=>[8, 9]}
```

```
char_indices('classroom')
  #=> {"c"=>[0], "l"=>[1], "a"=>[2], "s"=>[3, 4], "r"=>[5], "o"=>
[6, 7], "m"=>[8]}
```

Notice how I've written the block variables: `|(c,i),h|`. This makes use of Ruby's [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) rules. See also [this article](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/) on the subject.

---

The method is equivalent to the following.

```
def char_indices(str)
  h = {}
  str.each_char.
      with_index do |c,i|
        h[c] = [] unless h.key?(c)
        h[c] << i
      end
  h
end
```

---

One could alternatively write the method like this:

```
def char_indices(str)       
  str.each_char.
      with_index.
      with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(c,i),h| h[c] << i }
end
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html) that takes a block and no argument. If

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

than, possibly after keys have been added, if `h.key?(k) #=> false`, `h[k] = []` is executed. Here, when

```
h[c] << i
```

is encountered, if `h.key?(c) #=> false`, `h[c] = []` is executed, after which `h[c] << i` is executed, resulting in `h[c] #=> [c]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `h[el] = []<<i`. Instead you can use conditional assignment to ensure that you're working with an array:

```
def char_indices(string)
  string.each_char
        .with_index
        .with_object({}) do |(char, index), hash|
          hash[char] ||= []
          hash[char] << index
       end
end
```

Comment: Question about your formatting: is it "Best practice" to separate methods in this fashion for clarity or simply preference?
thank you for edit and response!

Comment: Its really a question of preference as long as you use a sensible line length metric (such as 80 characters). Breaking down long method chains helps readibility which is good for maintainence. I would rather have two lines then  `(h[c] ||= []) << i` which is very terse.